# How to count specific characters in string - CSH

Tags: linux, string, shell, csh, tcsh

How can I count specific characters in string - CSH.

```
set my_path = "/home/user/docs/files"
set sum = ???
```

Let's say, we need to count '/'

Comment: Do you really have to use `csh`? It's terrible for scripting. http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: yes, I have to.. or tcsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use any external tools you can do it with only `tcsh` (with an ugly workaround):

```
$ set my_path = "/home/user/docs/files"
$ set tmp= ( ${my_path:as,/, x,} )
$ set sum=${#tmp}
$ echo ${sum}
4
```

A little explanation to `set tmp= ( ${my_path:as,/, x,} )`: we replace (`s`) all (`a`) `/` character to `x` (space and x) and create an array from these words (separated by spaces). The `${#tmp}` counts the words in `${tmp}`. See more [man tcsh](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcsh(1)) (chapter "History substitution").

I think this solution is very ugly and works *only in your case* (for example doesn't produce the desired value if you remove the first `/`).

I hope you can use external tools - only `grep` and `wc`:

```
$ set sum=`echo ${my_path} | grep -o '/' | wc -l`
$ echo ${sum}
4
```

This version is better because doesn't need any workaround and works in other cases. If you can please choose this solution.

Comment: it looks great, but when I run script, this error comes: grep: illegal option --o

Comment: Please note: `-o` and not `--o`! Only one `-` character :) The long version of this option is `--only-matching`.

Comment: I checked "man grep", and my grep does not support option -o. I do not understand :(

Comment: What version of your grep? GNU grep supports it (assume your version is GNU because of `linux` tag of your question).

Comment: GNU grep version 2.0

Comment: Maybe you can replace the "grep" to `tr '/' '\n'`. I think it should work.